# Not able to delete the record

Tags: configuration

User_X and User_A both belongs to country `FR`.

User_X's role (i.e 'France GM') is above the role of User_A in the role hierarchy.

User_A has created a record of `Presentations` custom object. Now User_X wants to delete this record that User_A has created. But in current configuration, he is not able to delete it. What to modify to allow User_X to delete records those are created by users(those are below of the role of User_X in the role hierarchy)?

OWD for `Presentations` custom object
[image]
Presentation Sharing Rules
[image]

User_X's profile has delete access to `Presentations` custom object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the checkbox "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" checkbox.

It will enable you to [Control the Access Using Role Hierarchies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&type=0)

Since User X's profile already has Delete permission, once they gain access to the record thru role hierarchy they should be able to delete the record.